# minio presignedPutObject generated URL only valid for days, how to make it public always without days restriction

Tags: minio

I am working on Minio server, using presignedPutObject method can generate a public visiting URL, however this URL can only work for 7 days by default, I tried to extend it to 30 days but restricted.

so how would I try to make all the uploaded files with public permission which the generated URL can exist forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the 7 day limit is an [S3 Spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html#who-presigned-url) limitation rather than a MinIO limitation.

If you need indefinite unauthenticated access to a bucket, you can instead set a read-only bucket policy via `mc policy set --recursive download play/bucket/prefix/`:

Beyond that , to my knowledge we adhere to the S3 spec on the expiration of presigned URLs.